# How can I format a string sheet to date with Query

Tags: date, google-sheets-formula, string-formatting, spreadsheet, google-query-language

I have a col on googlesheet, that I need convert to date time with query function.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| nome1 | 2022-11-17T13:41:47.431Z |
| name2 | 2022-11-17T13:41:47.431Z |

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| nome1 | 2022-11-17 13:41:47 |
| name2 | 2022-11-17 13:41:47 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({A1:A, TEXT(REGEXREPLACE(B1:B,
 "[TZ]", " "), "e-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")}))
```

[image]